# How to resolve Mosquitto issue of protocol error

Tags: mqtt, protocols, ubuntu-18.04, mosquitto

I have installed mosquitto in Ubuntu18.04

```
mosquitto version 2.0.14

mosquitto is an MQTT v5.0/v3.1.1/v3.1 broker.

Usage: mosquitto [-c config_file] [-d] [-h] [-p port]

 -c : specify the broker config file.
 -d : put the broker into the background after starting.
 -h : display this help.
 -p : start the broker listening on the specified port.
      Not recommended in conjunction with the -c option.
 -v : verbose mode - enable all logging types. This overrides
      any logging options given in the config file.

See https://mosquitto.org/ for more information.
```

Below is the content of `mosquitto.conf`

```
# Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
#
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
```

Below is the content of `bridge.conf`

```
connection iothub-bridge
log_type all
address ripe.azure-devices.net:8883
remote_username ripe.azure-devices.net/T45
remote_password SharedAccessSignature sr=ripe.azure-devices.net&sig=V0ydOeJN3UHpD1l63kyz%2Bj0ks8XvZR1YDlBvqQK4a4Q%3D&se=253402280999.23&skn=iothubowner
remote_clientid T45
bridge_cafile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
try_private false
cleansession false
start_type automatic
bridge_insecure false
bridge_protocol_version mqttv311
bridge_tls_version tlsv1.2
notifications false

keepalive_interval 36000
autosave_interval 30

topic # out 2 devices/T45/messages/events/ devices/T45/messages/events/
topic # in 2 devices/T45/messages/devicebound/ devices/T45/messages/devicebound/
```

In the logs I can see

```
Client local.T45 disconnected: Protocol error.
```

What does this error means and how can I resolve it? Please help. Thanks

Below are the logs from `/var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log` where exactly at `1644460186` you can notice `protocol error` (I have put spaces between line to make it more appearing)

```
1644460056: mosquitto version 2.0.14 starting
1644460056: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1644460056: Starting in local only mode. Connections will only be possible from clients running on this machine.
1644460056: Create a configuration file which defines a listener to allow remote access.
1644460056: For more details see https://mosquitto.org/documentation/authentication-methods/
1644460056: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1644460056: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1644460056: Bridge local.T45 doing local SUBSCRIBE on topic devices/T45/messages/events/#
1644460056: Connecting bridge (step 1) iothub-bridge_1 (ripe.azure-devices.net:8883)
1644460056: mosquitto version 2.0.14 running
1644460056: Connecting bridge (step 2) iothub-bridge_1 (ripe.azure-devices.net:8883)
1644460056: Bridge T45 sending CONNECT
1644460057: New connection from 127.0.0.1:41643 on port 1883.
1644460057: New client connected from 127.0.0.1:41643 as Sender (p2, c1, k60).
1644460057: No will message specified.
1644460057: Sending CONNACK to Sender (0, 0)
1644460057: New connection from 127.0.0.1:56081 on port 1883.
1644460057: New client connected from 127.0.0.1:56081 as GateWay-1 (p2, c1, k120).
1644460057: No will message specified.
1644460057: Sending CONNACK to GateWay-1 (0, 0)
1644460057: Received SUBSCRIBE from Sender
1644460057:     raspberry/zigbee (QoS 0)
1644460057: Sender 0 raspberry/zigbee
1644460057: Sending SUBACK to Sender
1644460086: Saving in-memory database to /var/lib/mosquitto//mosquitto.db.
1644460086: Received PUBLISH from GateWay-1 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'raspberry/zigbee', ... (163 bytes))
1644460086: Sending PUBLISH to Sender (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'raspberry/zigbee', ... (163 bytes))
1644460086: New connection from 127.0.0.1:41721 on port 1883.
1644460086: New client connected from 127.0.0.1:41721 as auto-A6AC5150-859B-6481-F115-F5A4E2A78E38 (p2, c1, k60).
1644460086: No will message specified.
1644460086: Sending CONNACK to auto-A6AC5150-859B-6481-F115-F5A4E2A78E38 (0, 0)
1644460086: Received PUBLISH from GateWay-1 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'raspberry/zigbee', ... (368 bytes))
1644460086: Sending PUBLISH to Sender (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'raspberry/zigbee', ... (368 bytes))
1644460086: Received PUBLISH from auto-A6AC5150-859B-6481-F115-F5A4E2A78E38 (d0, q1, r0, m1, 'devices/T45/messages/events/', ... (496 bytes))
1644460086: Sending PUBACK to auto-A6AC5150-859B-6481-F115-F5A4E2A78E38 (m1, rc0)
1644460086: Received DISCONNECT from auto-A6AC5150-859B-6481-F115-F5A4E2A78E38
1644460086: Client auto-A6AC5150-859B-6481-F115-F5A4E2A78E38 disconnected.
1644460086: New connection from 127.0.0.1:39873 on port 1883.
1644460086: New client connected from 127.0.0.1:39873 as auto-AF07BB04-B557-4BF2-D493-CBF76F405156 (p2, c1, k60).
1644460086: No will message specified.
1644460086: Sending CONNACK to auto-AF07BB04-B557-4BF2-D493-CBF76F405156 (0, 0)
1644460086: Received PUBLISH from auto-AF07BB04-B557-4BF2-D493-CBF76F405156 (d0, q1, r0, m1, 'devices/T45/messages/events/', ... (325 bytes))
1644460086: Sending PUBACK to auto-AF07BB04-B557-4BF2-D493-CBF76F405156 (m1, rc0)
1644460086: Received DISCONNECT from auto-AF07BB04-B557-4BF2-D493-CBF76F405156
1644460086: Client auto-AF07BB04-B557-4BF2-D493-CBF76F405156 disconnected.
1644460100: Received PUBLISH from GateWay-1 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'raspberry/zigbee', ... (368 bytes))
1644460100: Sending PUBLISH to Sender (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'raspberry/zigbee', ... (368 bytes))
1644460100: New connection from 127.0.0.1:38321 on port 1883.
1644460100: New client connected from 127.0.0.1:38321 as auto-35DA741A-5DF9-2344-E252-8ED90D074794 (p2, c1, k60).
1644460100: No will message specified.
1644460100: Sending CONNACK to auto-35DA741A-5DF9-2344-E252-8ED90D074794 (0, 0)
1644460100: Received PUBLISH from auto-35DA741A-5DF9-2344-E252-8ED90D074794 (d0, q1, r0, m1, 'devices/T45/messages/events/', ... (325 bytes))
1644460100: Sending PUBACK to auto-35DA741A-5DF9-2344-E252-8ED90D074794 (m1, rc0)
1644460100: Received DISCONNECT from auto-35DA741A-5DF9-2344-E252-8ED90D074794
1644460100: Client auto-35DA741A-5DF9-2344-E252-8ED90D074794 disconnected.
1644460103: Received PUBLISH from GateWay-1 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'raspberry/zigbee', ... (163 bytes))
1644460103: Sending PUBLISH to Sender (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'raspberry/zigbee', ... (163 bytes))
1644460103: New connection from 127.0.0.1:40241 on port 1883.
1644460103: New client connected from 127.0.0.1:40241 as auto-748D1EFE-8960-472B-D381-6EEC8AC4FF2F (p2, c1, k60).
1644460103: No will message specified.
1644460103: Sending CONNACK to auto-748D1EFE-8960-472B-D381-6EEC8AC4FF2F (0, 0)
1644460103: Received PUBLISH from GateWay-1 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'raspberry/zigbee', ... (368 bytes))
1644460103: Sending PUBLISH to Sender (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'raspberry/zigbee', ... (368 bytes))
1644460103: Received PUBLISH from auto-748D1EFE-8960-472B-D381-6EEC8AC4FF2F (d0, q1, r0, m1, 'devices/T45/messages/events/', ... (496 bytes))
1644460103: Sending PUBACK to auto-748D1EFE-8960-472B-D381-6EEC8AC4FF2F (m1, rc0)
1644460103: Received DISCONNECT from auto-748D1EFE-8960-472B-D381-6EEC8AC4FF2F
1644460103: Client auto-748D1EFE-8960-472B-D381-6EEC8AC4FF2F disconnected.
1644460103: New connection from 127.0.0.1:58641 on port 1883.
1644460103: New client connected from 127.0.0.1:58641 as auto-BCD5D50F-D690-16D0-3780-D3C12004407B (p2, c1, k60).
1644460103: No will message specified.
1644460103: Sending CONNACK to auto-BCD5D50F-D690-16D0-3780-D3C12004407B (0, 0)
1644460103: Received PUBLISH from auto-BCD5D50F-D690-16D0-3780-D3C12004407B (d0, q1, r0, m1, 'devices/T45/messages/events/', ... (325 bytes))
1644460103: Sending PUBACK to auto-BCD5D50F-D690-16D0-3780-D3C12004407B (m1, rc0)
1644460103: Received DISCONNECT from auto-BCD5D50F-D690-16D0-3780-D3C12004407B
1644460103: Client auto-BCD5D50F-D690-16D0-3780-D3C12004407B disconnected.
1644460116: Received PUBLISH from GateWay-1 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'raspberry/zigbee', ... (163 bytes))
1644460116: Sending PUBLISH to Sender (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'raspberry/zigbee', ... (163 bytes))
1644460116: Received PUBLISH from GateWay-1 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'raspberry/zigbee', ... (369 bytes))
1644460116: Sending PUBLISH to Sender (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'raspberry/zigbee', ... (369 bytes))
1644460116: New connection from 127.0.0.1:50139 on port 1883.
1644460116: New client connected from 127.0.0.1:50139 as auto-BBCFAC32-DD66-649D-ECD9-C428AC01DCA7 (p2, c1, k60).
1644460116: No will message specified.
1644460116: Sending CONNACK to auto-BBCFAC32-DD66-649D-ECD9-C428AC01DCA7 (0, 0)
1644460116: Received PUBLISH from auto-BBCFAC32-DD66-649D-ECD9-C428AC01DCA7 (d0, q1, r0, m1, 'devices/T45/messages/events/', ... (496 bytes))
1644460116: Sending PUBACK to auto-BBCFAC32-DD66-649D-ECD9-C428AC01DCA7 (m1, rc0)
1644460116: Received DISCONNECT from auto-BBCFAC32-DD66-649D-ECD9-C428AC01DCA7
1644460116: Client auto-BBCFAC32-DD66-649D-ECD9-C428AC01DCA7 disconnected.
1644460116: New connection from 127.0.0.1:59883 on port 1883.
1644460116: New client connected from 127.0.0.1:59883 as auto-5ED9ADF5-E029-1CBB-C86E-11129A40653A (p2, c1, k60).
1644460116: No will message specified.
1644460116: Sending CONNACK to auto-5ED9ADF5-E029-1CBB-C86E-11129A40653A (0, 0)
1644460116: Received PUBLISH from auto-5ED9ADF5-E029-1CBB-C86E-11129A40653A (d0, q1, r0, m1, 'devices/T45/messages/events/', ... (325 bytes))
1644460116: Sending PUBACK to auto-5ED9ADF5-E029-1CBB-C86E-11129A40653A (m1, rc0)
1644460116: Received DISCONNECT from auto-5ED9ADF5-E029-1CBB-C86E-11129A40653A
1644460116: Client auto-5ED9ADF5-E029-1CBB-C86E-11129A40653A disconnected.
1644460117: Saving in-memory database to /var/lib/mosquitto//mosquitto.db.
1644460118: Received PINGREQ from Sender
1644460118: Sending PINGRESP to Sender
1644460146: Received PUBLISH from GateWay-1 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'raspberry/zigbee', ... (162 bytes))
1644460146: Sending PUBLISH to Sender (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'raspberry/zigbee', ... (162 bytes))
1644460146: Received PUBLISH from GateWay-1 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'raspberry/zigbee', ... (368 bytes))
1644460146: Sending PUBLISH to Sender (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'raspberry/zigbee', ... (368 bytes))
1644460146: New connection from 127.0.0.1:55549 on port 1883.
1644460146: New client connected from 127.0.0.1:55549 as auto-DA933222-650B-4F6B-7C1A-FC44C9301551 (p2, c1, k60).
1644460146: No will message specified.
1644460146: Sending CONNACK to auto-DA933222-650B-4F6B-7C1A-FC44C9301551 (0, 0)
1644460146: Received PUBLISH from auto-DA933222-650B-4F6B-7C1A-FC44C9301551 (d0, q1, r0, m1, 'devices/T45/messages/events/', ... (495 bytes))
1644460146: Sending PUBACK to auto-DA933222-650B-4F6B-7C1A-FC44C9301551 (m1, rc0)
1644460146: Received DISCONNECT from auto-DA933222-650B-4F6B-7C1A-FC44C9301551
1644460146: Client auto-DA933222-650B-4F6B-7C1A-FC44C9301551 disconnected.
1644460146: New connection from 127.0.0.1:51399 on port 1883.
1644460146: New client connected from 127.0.0.1:51399 as auto-678EC03F-ABB6-CA64-00DB-BDD47F57337D (p2, c1, k60).
1644460146: No will message specified.
1644460146: Sending CONNACK to auto-678EC03F-ABB6-CA64-00DB-BDD47F57337D (0, 0)
1644460146: Received PUBLISH from auto-678EC03F-ABB6-CA64-00DB-BDD47F57337D (d0, q1, r0, m1, 'devices/T45/messages/events/', ... (325 bytes))
1644460146: Sending PUBACK to auto-678EC03F-ABB6-CA64-00DB-BDD47F57337D (m1, rc0)
1644460146: Received DISCONNECT from auto-678EC03F-ABB6-CA64-00DB-BDD47F57337D
1644460146: Client auto-678EC03F-ABB6-CA64-00DB-BDD47F57337D disconnected.
1644460148: Saving in-memory database to /var/lib/mosquitto//mosquitto.db.
1644460161: Received PUBLISH from GateWay-1 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'raspberry/zigbee', ... (368 bytes))
1644460161: Sending PUBLISH to Sender (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'raspberry/zigbee', ... (368 bytes))
1644460161: New connection from 127.0.0.1:40109 on port 1883.
1644460161: New client connected from 127.0.0.1:40109 as auto-E898C4CD-622A-1271-CFBE-242783E578EC (p2, c1, k60).
1644460161: No will message specified.
1644460161: Sending CONNACK to auto-E898C4CD-622A-1271-CFBE-242783E578EC (0, 0)
1644460161: Received PUBLISH from auto-E898C4CD-622A-1271-CFBE-242783E578EC (d0, q1, r0, m1, 'devices/T45/messages/events/', ... (325 bytes))
1644460161: Sending PUBACK to auto-E898C4CD-622A-1271-CFBE-242783E578EC (m1, rc0)
1644460161: Received DISCONNECT from auto-E898C4CD-622A-1271-CFBE-242783E578EC
1644460161: Client auto-E898C4CD-622A-1271-CFBE-242783E578EC disconnected.
1644460176: Received PUBLISH from GateWay-1 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'raspberry/zigbee', ... (163 bytes))
1644460176: Sending PUBLISH to Sender (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'raspberry/zigbee', ... (163 bytes))
1644460176: Received PUBLISH from GateWay-1 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'raspberry/zigbee', ... (369 bytes))
1644460176: Sending PUBLISH to Sender (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'raspberry/zigbee', ... (369 bytes))
1644460176: New connection from 127.0.0.1:45683 on port 1883.
1644460176: New client connected from 127.0.0.1:45683 as auto-416D5585-0094-6CA2-5EC5-FBDC14A440D3 (p2, c1, k60).
1644460176: No will message specified.
1644460176: Sending CONNACK to auto-416D5585-0094-6CA2-5EC5-FBDC14A440D3 (0, 0)
1644460176: Received PUBLISH from auto-416D5585-0094-6CA2-5EC5-FBDC14A440D3 (d0, q1, r0, m1, 'devices/T45/messages/events/', ... (496 bytes))
1644460176: Sending PUBACK to auto-416D5585-0094-6CA2-5EC5-FBDC14A440D3 (m1, rc0)
1644460176: Received DISCONNECT from auto-416D5585-0094-6CA2-5EC5-FBDC14A440D3
1644460176: Client auto-416D5585-0094-6CA2-5EC5-FBDC14A440D3 disconnected.
1644460176: New connection from 127.0.0.1:44277 on port 1883.
1644460176: New client connected from 127.0.0.1:44277 as auto-C39DB933-9085-5256-90ED-8ADB846CFE7C (p2, c1, k60).
1644460176: No will message specified.
1644460176: Sending CONNACK to auto-C39DB933-9085-5256-90ED-8ADB846CFE7C (0, 0)
1644460176: Received PUBLISH from auto-C39DB933-9085-5256-90ED-8ADB846CFE7C (d0, q1, r0, m1, 'devices/T45/messages/events/', ... (325 bytes))
1644460176: Sending PUBACK to auto-C39DB933-9085-5256-90ED-8ADB846CFE7C (m1, rc0)
1644460176: Received DISCONNECT from auto-C39DB933-9085-5256-90ED-8ADB846CFE7C
1644460176: Client auto-C39DB933-9085-5256-90ED-8ADB846CFE7C disconnected.
1644460177: Received PINGREQ from GateWay-1
1644460177: Sending PINGRESP to GateWay-1
1644460178: Received PINGREQ from Sender
1644460178: Sending PINGRESP to Sender
1644460179: Saving in-memory database to /var/lib/mosquitto//mosquitto.db.

1644460186: Client local.T45 disconnected: Protocol error.

1644460194: Bridge local.T45 doing local SUBSCRIBE on topic devices/T45/messages/events/#
1644460194: Connecting bridge (step 1) iothub-bridge_1 (ripe.azure-devices.net:8883)
1644460195: Connecting bridge (step 2) iothub-bridge_1 (ripe.azure-devices.net:8883)
1644460195: Bridge T45 sending CONNECT
1644460205: Received PUBLISH from GateWay-1 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'raspberry/zigbee', ... (368 bytes))
1644460205: Sending PUBLISH to Sender (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'raspberry/zigbee', ... (368 bytes))
1644460205: New connection from 127.0.0.1:46557 on port 1883.
1644460205: New client connected from 127.0.0.1:46557 as auto-B4334155-551F-34B4-2214-66DFF50D4F5C (p2, c1, k60).
1644460205: No will message specified.
```

Comment: Please provide additional log entries (currently its not clear if the connection comes up and then drops or never connects). One potential issue is that ["IoT Hub does not support QoS 2 messages"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#sending-device-to-cloud-messages) and your config specifies QOS 2 for the bridge.

Comment: @Brits I have previously used the same bridge file with QOS 2 with Azure IOT hub. I think this latest version `2.0.14` is creating some issues because version `2.0.12` I installed 3 months back and its working fine. Anyways I have added logs. Thanks

Comment: Okay so client had the ports blocked, so when I connected the ubuntu with mobile hotspot it started working. Anyways thanks